# CSS unwanted vertical space

Tags: css

When I enter more than one line of content in the 'wrap' div it creates vertical space at the bottom of the div. How can I prevent this?

[Screen shot](http://tinypic.com/r/2dt4xat/6)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nD9nN/embedded/result/)

HTML

```
<div id="widgets">
  <div id="wrap">
   <h1 class="name" >Models</h1>
     <li><a href="">Rename a column</a></li>
     <li><a href="">git add all new or modified files</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Heroku assets:precompile plugin </a></li>
     <li><a href="">Heroku tail logs</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Rename a column</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Heroku load db:schema </a></li>
     <li><a href="">Heroku: connect to database </a></li>
     <li><a href="">Postgres: show tables</a></li>
     <li><a href="">git switch to a branch </a></li>
     <li><a href="">add records from console </a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#widgets {
margin: 15px 0px 50px 15px;
text-align: center;
}

#wrap {  
margin: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
text-align: left;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
padding: 1px 20px 5px 20px;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nD9nN/embedded/result/

Comment: That's invalid HTML. `<li>` elements may not be direct descendants of `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Arman P.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376527/552067) works, but if you want to keep using your inline-block method instead of floats like you are now, you can just add this:

```
#wrap {    
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add float: left to your #wrap css declaration. Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nD9nN/1/embedded/result/).

```
#wrap { float: left; }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Arman. I had that in there earlier but 100 edits later forgot about it.

Comment: It was collapsing problem, you can read on it here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/